# Continuous martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I have a general question regarding the notion of "continuous martingale". Does this expression refer to a continuous time stochastic process that has the property of being a  martingale  or does it refer to a martingale that has continuous paths?
I would say the first definition should be the one it refers to (the second it refers generally to BM only, right?) but I get unsure since some articles I am reading do not define the concept form the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, a stochastic process is called a *continuous martingale* if it is a martingale and has continuous sample paths. (Note that not any martingale with continuous sample paths is a Brownian motion.)